# Twitter Webhooks using Nodejs, Authenicating Issue

Tags: node.js, twitter, webhooks

I m trying to build a web app to handle webhooks from Twitter.
I m following this [doc](https://github.com/twitterdev/twitter-webhook-boilerplate-node).

Everytime, when I try to register my webhook url, I m getting this issue

> {"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}

Here is my code snippet which I m calling to register the URL.

```
app.get('/subscribe-twitter-webhooks', (req, res) => {
        // twitter authentication
        var twitter_oauth = {
            consumer_key: 'CONSUMER_KEY',
            consumer_secret: 'CONSUMER_SECRET',
            token: 'ACCESS_TOKEN',
            token_secret: 'TOKEN_SECRET'
        };

        var WEBHOOK_URL = 'https://api.mydomain.com/twitter/webhooks';

        // request options
        var request_options = {
            url: 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account_activity/webhooks.json',
            oauth: twitter_oauth,
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            form: {
                url: WEBHOOK_URL
            }
        }
        // POST request to create webhook config
        request.post(request_options, function (error, response, body) {
            console.log('--er--', error)
            console.log('--body--', body)
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a library/package to handle connecting to the Twitter API (I use [twit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twit)), as it would handle the encoding and auth for you.

Comment: I want to get analytic data of all the tweets for an user. How can I achieve that using this?